# Special decomposition of polymonial from $R[x]$, where $R$-UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be UFD. Given the polynomial $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_mx^m$ in
> $R[x]$, then *the content of $f(x)$* is defined to be gcd of
> $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n$. It is uniqie within units of $R$. We shall denote
> the content of $f(x)$ by $c(f)$. A polynomial in $R[x]$ is said to be
> *primitive* if its content is 1 (that is, is a unit in $R$). Given any polunomial $f(x)\in R[x]$, we can write $f(x)=af_1(x)$ where $a=c(f)$
> and where $f_1(x)\in R[x]$ is primitive (it is not so difficult to
> prove!).
>
> Except for multiplication by units of $R$ this decomposition of
> $f(x)$, as an element of $R$ by a primitive polynomial in $R[x]$, is
> unique!

More presicely, the last paragraph is equivalent to the following:

**Claim:** Let $R$ - UFD and $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_mx^m$ in $R[x]$.

If $f(x)=ap(x)$ and $f(x)=bq(x)$ where $a,b\in R$ and $p(x),q(x)$ - primitive **then** $a\sim b$, $p(x)\sim q(x)$.

I proved this when $f(x)\neq 0$ and the proof is not so difficult.

But I guess that this is incorrect if $f(x)=0$. For example, let's take $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and consider $f(x)=0$ with $a=b=0, p(x)=x+1, q(x)=x^2+1$. We see that $a\sim b$ but $p(x)\nsim q(x)$.

Am I right?

P.S. This excerpt from Herstein's book (page 163).

Comment: You are correct, you need to assume that $f$ is nonzero for the decomposition to be unique.

Comment: @MikeEarnest, Thanks!